# When to use imperfect subjunctive vs past perfect subjunctive

Tags: grammar, subjunctive-mood

Consider the following two sentences

1. Speravo che trasmettessero la conferenza in diretta. (I hoped they would broadcast the conference live.)
2. Speravo che avessero trasmesso la conferenza in diretta. (I hoped they would have broadcast the conference live.)

My understanding is that the first sentence is in imperfect subjunctive, and the second sentence is in past perfect subjunctive. Does one sentence sound more natural than the other? In what case is one used vs the other? Even in English, I'm not sure how to explain the semantic difference between those two sentences...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The second sentence means that at some time you had the hope that, at an earlier time, the conference had been broadcast.

Comment: Your translation into English seems incorrect. The second sentence, I think, should be a "past in the past", and as far as I understand in English this is expressed with "I hoped they had broadcasted the conference live".

Answer (score 0):

Proveró di rispondere alla tua domanda.

In "Speravo che trasmettessero la conferenza in diretta" non indica chiaramente che non l'hanno trasmessa infatti. L'attenzione versa sulla tua speranza.

In "Speravo che avessero trassmesso la conferenza" invece, lo scopo è spiegare che in un determinato momento, più specifico, tua aspettativa è rotta dal fatto non compiuto dagli altri.  L'attenzione versa sul fatto non compiuto.

Spero che ti abbia aiutato.

Comment: @DaG I commenti in SE andrebbero usati per chiedere informazioni o suggerire miglioramenti; ti consiglierei di rendere più costruttive le tue osservazioni spiegando più nel dettaglio cosa non va nella risposta. Cerchiamo di essere amichevoli, soprattutto visto che si tratta di un nuovo utente (benvenuto!).

Comment: Hai ragione, @FedericoPoloni, e ti ringrazio. In attesa di poter scrivere eventualmente una risposta (o che lo faccia qualcun altro), volevo mettere in guardia eventuali lettori da questa. È innegabile che è scritta da qualcuno volenteroso, ma la cui conoscenza dell'italiano lascia molto a desiderare.